# Robot framework, AndroidLibrary: How to get Locator value to access an view for keyword "Set Text Locator Value"?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to enter a value to the edit View using keyword "Set Text". But I do not understand what to put for argument "Locator"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"locator" is a term borrowed from selenium, and describes a string that identifies an object in the UI. For a web based app a locator might be an object id, an xpath, a css path, etc. For AndroidLibrary, the locator should be either an integer or the string "num=<int>" (eg: num=3), or "name=<string>" for a named field (eg: name=username).